# R Plotly stacked or filled bar chart show not correctly aligned bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I do have the issue depicted below with filled or stacked bar charts using plotly. While the actual ggplot chart is perfectly aligned, I encounter the below issue in plotly.

```r
library(plotly)

#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout
e <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, fill = cyl))
f <- e + geom_col(position = "fill")
f
```

[image]

```r
ggplotly(f)
```

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using geom_bar(stat=“identity”, position=“fill”) instead of geom_col.